Purgatory in Peter Hamilton's Nights Dawn Trilogy
I read the nights dawn trilogy and I'm a bit confused on the idea of purgatory. At the end of the series we have the naked god send everyone in purgatory to the far future when the universe is being remade and all the souls will help form the next iteration... However earlier in the books it's unclear if everyone goes to purgatory and stays or if only "Bad" people stay and good ones naturally find a way to escape in the only direction allowed, which is again to the far future. It's also unclear if other aliens in universe have the same problem or not. Is this purgatory only for humans? Does it only trap the bad souls? Does it allow good people to exit to the future universe? Did the naked god send a bunch of baddies to help reform the next universe instead of leaving them there locked away? Also how does purgatory relate to the other cold dimension that has phantoms that drain energy...are they connected in some way?

It's been ages since I read this, but I recall that Edenists as a rule never ended up in the purgatory (not even Laton), as ending up there wasn't a moral consequence but a psychological one.  Other aliens had this same problem (or a similar issue at least), as it was mentioned that each civilization had to find their own solution to the problem.
